# How to locate the element inside td and <a

Tags: java, selenium

please help to locate the element by text "All documents" in Java

```
<td ....>
  <span class="11">
     <a onclick= ..... >
       All documents
     </a>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use xpath :

```
WebElement elementName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/a[contains(text(),'All documents')]"));
```

Comment: Great !! would you kind enough to  hit upvote button and accept answer from your end.